# Is Continuity a necessary condition for a function to be differentiable?

Tags: limits, derivatives

If 
$$f(x)={|x|\over x}$$
Which is kind of a sign Function except it's not defined at $x=0$
Is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$?
As the Right Differentiation of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ Equals to it's left Differentiation (I guess, since the slope of the function is 0 both at right and left of $x=0$)
And generally is continuity a Must to say that a function is differentiable at a particular point? Especially the cases which the discontinuity is about "Not being defined at $x=a$ though there exists a L that:
$$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)}=L$$
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: $\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac {f(x)-f(0)} x$ does no even make sense. What is your definition of $f'(0)$?

Comment: And to answer the question in the title: Yes, a differentiable function is always continuous as well. So continuity is necessary for a function to be differentiable.

Comment: You seem to believe that $f'_+(0)$ is the same thing as $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$, which it is not in general (for example, not in this case).

Answer (score 1):

If $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=L$$ then

$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-f(a))=\lim_{x\to a}L(x-a)=0.$$

Differentiability is stronger than continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply yes.
You are not even able to write the definition of derivative:
$$ f'(0):=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
You cannot write anything for $f(0)$.